# Add resolution mode for xorg-dummy

Tags: xorg, vnc

I am trying to to add a resolution mode for X with the xorg-dummy driver to be able to fit the x11vnc server's output to my screen resolution. 
I am running

```
x11vnc -xdummy -xrandr
```

with the x11vnc Xdummy script in my path. If I don't add a xorg.conf file in /etc/X11 then I get only a bunch of lower resolutions.

Therefore I added this xorg.conf file
https://www.xpra.org/xorg.conf
with which I also have a number of higher resolutions. Among them is 1920x1200 which I need, but rotated by 90 degrees.

Using http://www.arachnoid.com/modelines/ , I therefore computed the Modeline

```
Modeline "1200x1920_10.00" 27.20 1200 1192 1304 1408 1920 1921 1924 1932 -HSync +Vsync
```

And added it to the xorg.conf file together with the corresponding Mode. After restarting, however, I still don't have this mode. 
In my /var/log/Xorg.log I see thigs like

```
Not using mode "1200x1920" (no mode of this name)
```

but also

```
Not using mode "1920x1200" (no mode of this name)
```

The later works in fact. The former does not. I also tried adding it with xrandr, but I get

```
Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Furthermore I tried supplying the mode using the argument -geom 1200x1920 to the Xdummy script. This does not add the resolution either.

Does xorg-dummy only support the modes already specified in the sample xorg.conf or am I making a mistake? The goal of of the exercise is to be able to switch the vnc-server resolution dynamically. I could use other vnc-servers but most of these seem to have issues related to the use of KDE. KDE's own krfb is unfortunately much slower.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `xpra`. Sorry for not being able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official guide to compute *modeline* (with `cvt`) is here:

[*Resolution: Adding undetected resolutions*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

I think will be adequately to quote this part here:

> Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions
>   may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried
>   from your monitor may be incorrect.
>
> If the mode already exists, but just isn't associated for the
>   particular output, you can add it like this:
>
> ```
> $ xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600
> ```
>
> If the mode doesn't yet exist, you'll need to create it first by
>   specifying a *modeline*:
>
> ```
> $ xrandr --newmode <Mode``Line>
> ```
>
> You may create a modeline using the `gtf` or `cvt` utility. For example,
>   if you want to add a mode with resolution **800x600** at **60 Hz**, you can
>   enter the following command: (The output is shown following.)
>
> ```
> $ cvt 800 600 60
> # 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
> Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
> ```
>
> Then copy the information after the word "**Modeline**" into the `xrandr`
>   command:
>
> ```
> $ xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
> ```
>
> After the mode is entered, it needs to be added to the output using
>   the `--addmode` command as explained above.

Be careful and pay attention for last sentence.
Either, look your *modeline* for the words `-hsync +vsync` that typed with small letters. Use official guides. Enjoy.